# Safari Web Extension background request CORS issue

Tags: ios, swift, safari-extension, safari-web-extension

I am working on Safari Web Extension on on iOS 15, everything seems smooth so far except one thing:
The fetch request from background.js will always fail since it is cross origin and hence throws CORS error.

If I add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in server, the request is completed without any error. However, we are reluctant to allow all origins.

**Solutions tried**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: safari-web-extension://<guid>

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:< some request header we sent >
```

This didn't work because the GUID changes every-time the app is installed.

Any advice to resolve this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Once extension is published and installed via App Store, does it still get random UUID each time it's installed? If no, then respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <same as in request's origin>` on development server and with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: safari-web-extension://<guid-assigned-by-app-store-upon-first-publish>` on production server.